# Why the dashes above the two words "walillahi yasjudu"?

Tags: quran, reading-quran, sajdat-al-tilaawah

[image]
[image]

What do the horizontal lines above the words "walillahi yasjudu" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Some verses in the Quran when recited require  sajda/prostration called
**Sujud-Tilawa/Sajda tilawat *(prostration of recitation)***, the indication of this is ۩ or at the left/right side of the page, parallel to the verse ساجدة/سجدة is written. There is difference of opinion on whether it is wajib (essential) or mustahab (better).

These Sujud-Tilawa occur in these verses of the [Quran](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://quran411.com/sajdah-places-in-quran&ved=2ahUKEwiApMy2hLz7AhWY7rsIHWICCa8QFnoECDkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2BPrqUgeBZClI0adTgcRja):

- Surah Al A’Raf (7) Ayat 206
- Surah Al Ra’d (13) Ayat 15
- Surah Al Nahl (16) Ayat 50
- Surah Bani Israil (17) Ayat 109
- Surah Maryum (19) Ayat 58
- Surah Al Haj (22) Ayat 18
- Surah Al Haj (22) Ayat 77 (Shafi)
- Surah Al Farqan (25) Ayat 60
- Surah Al Naml (27) Ayat 26
- Surah As Sajdah (32) Ayat 15
- Surah Sa’d (38) Ayat 24 (Hanafi)
- Surah Hamim Sajdah (41) Ayat 38
- Surah Al Najam (53) Ayat 62
- Surah Inshiqaq (84) Ayat 21
- Surah Al Alaq (96) Ayat 19

**The dashes above/below some words of verses indicate the [reason of sajda-tilawat](https://instituteoflinguists.com/rules-signs-and-symbols-in-the-quran/).**

You can see all these dashes by [searching ۩ in quran.com](https://quran.com/search?page=1&q=%DB%A9&translations=20,131).

### Reasons of Sujud-Tilawa

- Disbelievers didn't prostate to Allah, so the believers prostate to Allah.
- The rightious and noble servants prostated to Allah, so the believers also prostate to Allah.
- Everything willingly/unwillingly prostates to Allah.
- Believers prostate to Allah, when Allah commanded(s) not to worship sun/moon.
- Allah commands believers/Muhammad (saw) to prostate.
- Some one worshiped/worships false deity(s) of Islam instead of Allah, so believers prostate to Allah.

---

You can learn more about the symbols in Quran [here](https://quran2hadith.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/meaning-of-symbols-and-signs-in-quran/) or just search [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=symbol+in+quran&oq=symbol+in+quran&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0i7i30l4j0i5i7i30l3j69i60.6884j0j9&client=ms-android-oppo-rvo3&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) .